# why (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0?

Tags: fetch-api

I need public data, so I'm going to bring it.

total api url : https://www.chungbuk.go.kr/openapi-json/pubdata/pubMapForest.do

```
fetch('/openapi-json/pubdata/pubMapForest.do?pageNo=1&numOfRows=2').then(
      (data) => data.json()).then(json=>console.log(json))
    );
```

// package.json

```
  "proxy":{
    "target":"https://www.chungbuk.go.kr"
  }
```

but I get strange data.
[image]
[image]

when i use postman, I got normal data.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried setting an explicit [`Accept` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) to tell the API you're hitting that you want JSON?

Comment: no i don't how use it?

Comment: Read the linked docs, research how to set request headers with `fetch`.

Comment: You're receiving an HTML document, not a JSON, hence the error. Check if the url is correct and what do you need to send to get a JSON response.